# How to click Chrome plugins like "Download" and "Print" button in qtp

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, qtplugin, uft-api, uft14

I was trying to download a pdf report and the download button was "chromes download plugin button" which i am not able to click using qtp script. The properties shown for all three buttons "Print","Download" and "Rotate" are same:

```
"html id:=plugin",
"html tag:=EMBED"
```

I couldn't initiate a click using these properties.

[image: Screenshot]

I am using UFT 12.02

And also , these buttons appears only when we hover the mouse pointer over the report.

Comment: @ManishChristian : I could click on these buttons only with the help of insight property as Motti mentioned...Click did not work ,when i used descriptive programming using properties:   "html id:=plugin",
"html tag:=EMBED" and index as 0,1 and 2 respectively for each elements. I think its because that these are chrome plugin buttons.

Comment: Thanks for checking and letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UFT doesn't typically support Chome's built in controls. 
For cases in which UFT doesn't support a specific control you can use **Insight**, UFT's image based object identification. You can read more about how [to use Insight here](https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/All-About-the-Apps/A-guide-to-Image-Based-Testing-with-HP-UFT-s-Insight/ba-p/252430).

If the buttons only appear when you hover over them then you can either use UFT's [device replay](http://burnignorance.com/software-testing-tips/simulating-mouse-click-operation-through-qtp/) in order to cause the buttons to appear, or simpler still, use Insight again which has a [`Hover` method](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#Insight/IBAPackageLib~InsightObject.html#Hover).